How can I simplify the visualization of comparative data across two dates and two variables to make it more compact and easier to interpret?
I am working on an analytics dashboard that allows the user to select a specific date among circular charts in the landing page. each chart contains coloring between variable 1 and benchmark of variable 1. red if variable1 > benchmark value, else green. Also, each chart contains coloring between variable 2 and benchmark of variable 2. blue if variable2 > benchmark value, else green.
here is my landing page:

in the landing page,  Variables Load section is easy to show only for instance 5. When the user clicks on Show details, then details page is opened. Left column is for Variable 1, and right column is for Variable 2. In the details page, user can see Instance 5 circular chart same from the landing page. Plus, user can also see difference circular chart between instance 5 and 4 as circular chart.
here is my details page:

In this details page, I am not sure about the design of Variables Load section. Since there will be two instances and two variables, how should I make a compact design it so that I minimize cognitive load and visible by the user without zooming in? Currently it shows variable 1 in the first row and then Variable 2 in the second row.

There are a few different things you could try, but it really depends on what kind of constraints you are working, because you have obviously had to make this section small, and the labels even smaller so that you can't actually see it.
The easiest thing is to put the labels for the values at the ends of the bars so you don't have to adjust the size of the values.
Regarding the overall layout for the variables load section, I would consider a visual hierarchy that optimizes the things that you want to compare, so that the right spacing is used to group items based on that hierarchy. Right now the spacing between variable 1 and 2 are the closest, followed by the categories and then the instances.
